# I download nopCommerce 4.20 Dotnet Core and upload on my plesk server. Timeout Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nopcommerce

[The site](http://ve.vasantsoftwaressolution.com) workins fine, but when I try to `Add order` or `Login/Registration` at the time I get `timeout` error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   BadHttpRequestException: Reading the request body timed out due to data arriving too slowly. See MinRequestBodyDataRate.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody.PumpAsync()

Comment: remove and re-install it again.

Comment: Already done. but its not working.

Comment: facing the same for the 4.1. Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401622/badhttprequestexception-due-to-minrequestbodydatarate-and-poor-connection

Comment: Yes I tired @sina_Islam

Comment: Does this woks?

Answer (score -1):

Most probably it's your database connectivity. Check your configurations in appsettings.json and checking if your database is accessible using the provided configurations

Answer (score -1):

Its because of memory allocated by your hosting provider. You need to change session storage In-Proc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. I added your given solution but its not working.